# Create a new column in pandas, using the multiple exact string matches with str.contains() or str.match()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with journals. I have different journals.

I want to extract journals with titles below only

```
Blood, Cancer, Chest, Circulation, Diabetes, JAMA, Endocrinology, Gastroenterology, Gut, Medicine, Neurology, Pediatrics, Physical therapy, Radiology, Surgery, Geriatrics
```

Some journals have the same words - Blood circulation, Cancer History, etc. I do not want to select them.

Example

```
Id Title
1  Blood
2  Blood
3  Blood purification
4  Blood transfusion
5  Cancer
6  Chest
7  Cancer History
8  Chest Analysis
```

I want to keep the exact journal title and create new column "Influential", but cannot find the way with `str.contains` or `str.match`.

I am trying two approaches

```
df.loc[df['Title'].str.contains("Blood", case = True, na = False), 'Influential'] = 'Blood'
df.loc[df['Title'].str.match("Blood", case = True, na = False), 'Influential'] = 'Blood'
```

Expected output with the exact title of the journal:

```
Id Title              Influential
1  Blood              Blood
2  Blood              Blood
3  Blood purification NA
4  Blood transfusion  NA
5  Cancer             Cancer
6  Chest              Chest
7  Cancer History     NA
8  Chest Analysis     NA
```

Should I do it somehow via `regex`? Thanks.

Comment: what should be in `Influential` if the title doesn't contain `blood`?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, for other Influential I have NAs

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, updated the expected output

Comment: `df['Influential'] = np.where(df.Title=='Blood', df.Title, np.NaN)`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, updated one more time

Comment: your question is really unclear. what is the rule for using the exact title? being just one word?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, updated again. I want to extract all titles with EXACT names only. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set `Influential` column values with the values from `Title` column if the latter is an exact match  of the words in your `lst` list, you can use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'Title': ['Blood','Blood', 'Blood purification', 'Blood transfusion', 'Cancer', 'Chest', 'Cancer History', 'Chest Analysis']})
lst = ['Blood', 'Chest', 'Cancer']
df['Influential'] = np.where(df['Title'].isin(lst), df['Title'], np.nan)
# >>> df
#    Id               Title Influential
# 0   1               Blood       Blood
# 1   2               Blood       Blood
# 2   3  Blood purification         NaN
# 3   4   Blood transfusion         NaN
# 4   5              Cancer      Cancer
# 5   6               Chest       Chest
# 6   7      Cancer History         NaN
# 7   8      Chest Analysis         NaN
```

Note the use of [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) (also [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70199080/create-a-new-column-in-pandas-using-the-exact-string-match-with-str-contains/70199348?noredirect=1#comment124093106_70199080)).

Comment: this works but it's better to avoid `apply` when performance is an issue - my answer (in the comment on OP's post) is more efficient

Comment: Wiktor, I updated the question slightly. What if I have multiple different title. The current solution overwrites everything besides a single title to NaN

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker So, if there is `Blood`, but with other text, then there must be `na`, else, the original is kept?

Comment: @Wiktor, I have a list of journals and want to create a column only for journals with the exact same name. Please see tha updated question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker `df['Influential'] = np.where(df['Title'].str.count(' ') == 0, df['Title'], np.nan)`? Or `np.where(df['Title'].str.count(r'\s') == 0, df['Title'], np.nan)` to account for any whitespace? I mean, do you only need to extract the title if it only contains one word?

Comment: I do not think it is the way. I have lst = ['Blood', "Chest', 'Cancer'] etc and I want to extract journals with these exact names only, not titles where the words above are a part of the title.

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker What do you mean by "exact match" here then? Only two specific words?

Comment: Wiktor, updated the initial question